# отправка письма на почту php по условию

Tags: php

есть таблица human с строкой e_mail с заполненными почтовыми адресами,
   и date_start с заполненной датой с начало его работы 
 мне надо отправить письмо на почту человека после истечения 5 дней со дня date_start как оповещение

Answer (score 0):

Выбираем письма из базы, и отправляем их. В MySQL как-то так

```
SELECT ... FROM table_name WHERE DATEDIFF(date_start, NOW()) >= 5
```

Comment: зачем выбирать письма из базы, надо выбрать email  с таблицы и на них отправить письмо с определенным контесктом если, канечно пройдет 5 дней со дня старта